# How execute this react-query mutation?

Tags: function, react-query

I have problem understanding this piece of code. How i can pass the id and data ?

```
function usePutCompany(id) {
  const [putCompany] = useMutation<any, any, any>(
    (data) => ApiCall.Company.put(id, data),
    {
      onSuccess() {
        queryCache.invalidateQueries('company')
        queryCache.refetchQueries('company')
      },
      throwOnError: true,
    },
  )

  return putCompany
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`id` is a parameter to the custom hook, and `data` is a parameter to the function returned by the hook. You would use this custom hook like this:

```
function MyComponent() {
  const putCompany = usePutCompany(1)

  return <Button onClick={() => putCompany(data) />
}
```